# fetch multiple rows, store in 1 variable and insert into table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to fetch bulk record and insert into table using loop
I have little confusion how to fetch and insert record using loop. Below I have shared  what I have done so far .

```
declare
    stud_Id varchar;
begin            
    stud_Id := select student_id from student_backup where is_active_flg ='Y';

    for i in 1 ..stud_Id.count
    loop
        insert into users(student_id,password,status) values(stud_Id(i),'password','status')
        where not exists (select student_id from users where student_id=stud_Id(i))
    end loop;

    commit;
end;
/
```

Comment: should i have to use array variable or something else for student_id

Comment: try this link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/a_samps.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
declare
  stud_Id student_backup.student_id%type;
begin
     select nvl(max(student_id),0) into stud_Id 
       from student_backup 
      where is_active_flg ='Y';

   if stud_Id >0 then
    for i in 1 ..stud_Id
    loop
       insert into users(student_id,password,status) 
       select b.student_id,'password','status'
         from student_backup b 
         left join users u on b.student_id = u.student_id
        where is_active_flg ='Y'
          and b.student_id = i;
    end loop;
   end if; 
    commit;
end;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b411ef4f78a2f0d3a13a4d9295babe4b)</kbd>

P.S. If I understood you want to perform, you don't need to use for loop(*including if statement*) and the select statement in the beginning, but directly apply the insert statement by removing the part `and b.student_id = i`.
So, convert your block to the one as below :

```
declare
  stud_Id student_backup.student_id%type;
begin

       insert into users(student_id,password,status) 
       select b.student_id,'password','status'
         from student_backup b 
         left join users u on b.student_id = u.student_id
        where is_active_flg ='Y' ;
    commit;
end;
/
```

Comment: dear can you please elaborate why you use max(student_id) instead of count(student_id).

Comment: hi @AbdulRaheem. I thought you need to scan all the possible values of student_id. If some not exists between 1 and max(student_id), then it's already skipped, and iterate to the max value.

Comment: @AbdulRaheem assume you have 50 students with ID through 1 to 100. Whenever `1..count(student_id)` is used for the loop, the ID with 51 to 100 will not be considered.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan you won't hit a `no_data_found` exception with a `max` query.

Comment: @AbdulRaheem excuse me, there was a mistake(was trying to look up in the same table `users`). Replaced `from users` with `from dual`. You can try it once again.

Comment: @AbdulRaheem I don't know how these two tables related. Do you want to insert into users table, provided the matching student_id is active (is_active_flg ='Y') within the `student_backup` table ? If so, we need to derive `exists` keyword in the SQL for `student_backup` tables.

Comment: Do you want to insert into users table, provided the matching student_id is active (is_active_flg ='Y') , YES . but  in student_backup table some student_id have have same value that is why i use insert student_id in users if already not inserted in users, can you please modify query

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan sir can i get your email and skype id please

Comment: Hi @AbdulRaheem. I don't use skype. My e-mail is barbaros_ozhan@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

Abdul,

I think you are searching for the following:

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO USERS 
SELECT STUDENT_ID, PASSWORD , STATUS
FROM student_backup
WHERE STUDENT_ID NOT IN (SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM USERS)
AND is_active_flg = 'Y';

END;
/
```

Hope, this will be useful.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bfbdf9fdd596df030d7f3e631d4e94bf)